# I have a missing semicolon per JSLint

Tags: javascript, jquery, syntax-error, jslint

My JS code:

```
$("#1").autocomplete(
{
    source: function (request, response)
    {
        "use strict";
        $.ajax(
        {
            url: "http://www.domain.com/foo/",
            dataType: "jsonp",
            data: {
                api_key: "123",
                search_term: request.term
            },
            success: function (data)
            {
                response($.map(data.data, function (item)
                {
                    return {
                        label: item.username,
                        value: item.user_id
                    }
                }));
            }
        });
    },
    minLength: 2
});
```

JSLint gives me the following error:

```
Error:
Problem at line 21 character 9: Expected ';' and instead saw '}'.

}
```

I don't see where this semicolon should go. What am I not seeing? The code works when I tested it.

Comment: Line 21, character 9, probably.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It wants it here;

```
                return {
                    label: item.username,
                    value: item.user_id
                }; <--
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 return {
                            label: item.username,
                            value: item.user_id
                        };
```

Answer (score 0):

```
return {
    label: item.username,
    value: item.user_id
}
```

should read

```
return {
    label: item.username,
    value: item.user_id
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Your ; needs to go after the return{} block. Consider using something like Notepad++ to pinpoint line numbers.